# Linking is no occuring in my Makefile; returns 'undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

This simple program (two .c files and one .h) compiles and links properly from the command line. However, my Makefile is throwing an error during the linking stage. Proper tab usage is in effect.

```
CC      = gcc
BINDIR  = bin/
OBJDIR  = obj/
SRCDIR  = src/
MKDIR   = mkdir -p
RM      = rm -rf

SRC     = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.c) 
_OBJS   = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%.c, %.o, $(SRC))
OBJS    = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(_OBJS))
CFLAGS  = -Wall -g -Iinclude

.PHONY: all
    all: $(BIN)

_BIN    = a.out
BIN     = $(addprefix $(BINDIR), $(_BIN))

$(BIN): $(OBJS) $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<  

$(BINDIR):
    $(MKDIR) $(BINDIR)

$(OBJS): $(SRC) $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

$(OBJDIR):
    $(MKDIR) $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning things up..."
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR) $(BINDIR)
```

The program's files:
main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "hellomake.h"

int main(void) {
    myPrintHelloMake();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

hellomake.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "hellomake.h"

void myPrintHelloMake(void) {
    puts("Hello makefiles!");
}
```

hellomake.h

```
#ifndef __HELLO_H__
#define __HELLO_H__

void myPrintHelloMake(void);

#endif
```

The .c files are in the src/ directory and the .h file is in the include/ directory. Makefile compiles the code, creates the obj/ directory, and places and main.o and hellomake.o therein. However, that is where things break down. Here is gcc's complaint:

```
$ make 
mkdir -p obj/
gcc -Wall -g -Iinclude -c src/hellomake.c -o obj/hellomake.o gcc -Wall -g -Iinclude -c src/hellomake.c -o obj/main.o mkdir -p bin/ gcc -o bin/a.out -Wall -g -Iinclude
obj/hellomake.o /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start': (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [Makefile:34: bin/a.out] Error 1
```

Comment: When you link (target `$(BIN)`), you need `$^` (all prerequisites)  instead of `$<` (only the first prerequisite), I think. (Okay, that will include the `$(BINDIR)`, so you may have to introduce an intermediary phony target, e.g. `all: $(BIN) %(BINDIR)`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of issues.

I'd leave off `/` from (e.g.) `BINDIR` et. al.

The `patsubst` was incorrect. It needed `$(OBJDIR)` in the the `TO`

Using `_OBJS` was unnecessary/harmful.

The rule for `$(OBJS)` was incorrect. It created the two `.o` files using the first prereq source, so [the function] `main` was defined twice. It needs a pattern rule instead.

Using `$(BINDIR)` as a prereq for `$(BIN)` added `bin/` at the end of the `gcc` line [and it complained]

As `M.Oehm` mentioned, `$<` only gets the first prereq.

The `all:` was *indented* so it was not recognized properly

---

Anyway, here's the corrected `Makefile`:

```
CC      = gcc
BINDIR  = bin
OBJDIR  = obj
SRCDIR  = src
MKDIR   = mkdir -p
RM      = rm -rf

SRC     = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)

###_OBJS   = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)%.c, %.o, $(SRC))
###OBJS    = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR), $(_OBJS))
OBJS   = $(patsubst $(SRCDIR)/%.c, $(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SRC))

CFLAGS  = -Wall -g -Iinclude

_BIN    = a.out
BIN     = $(addprefix $(BINDIR)/, $(_BIN))

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR) $(BIN)

####$(BIN): $(OBJS) $(BINDIR)
$(BIN): $(OBJS) $(BINDIR)
    ###$(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $(OBJS)

$(BINDIR):
    $(MKDIR) $(BINDIR)

###$(OBJS): $(SRC) $(OBJDIR)
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    $(MKDIR) $(OBJDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo "Cleaning things up..."
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR) $(BINDIR)
```